# I want to turn the string "random.randint(2,4), into an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a text based game, and I want players to be able to do battle with monsters throughout the game.  I have player stats stored in a dictionary, and for attack I am using the random.randint(a,b).  The problem is that this is stored outside of the while loop for the battle.  So the attack is always the same, but I want it to change throughout the loop.

The only thing that I could think of so far was to store it in the dictionary as a string and then use slice to take the quotation marks off and then use int() so that it's not an integer anymore.  Here's the last thing I tried.  Spells have been commented out until I can figure out

```
import random

player = {"attack":"(random.randint(2,4))", "health": 50}

goblin = {"name": "goblin", "attack": "(random.randint(1,3))", "health": 30}

def battle(user, monster):
        for key in player:
            if key != "health":
                print(key)
        while goblin["health"] > 0:
            user["attack"] = int(user["attack"][1:-1])
            monster["attack"] = int(monster["attack"][1:-1])
            print(user["attack"])
            print(monster["attack"])
            select = input("Would you like to attack or use a spell?")
            if select == "attack":
                print(user["attack"])
                goblin["health"] -= user["attack"]
                print("The", (monster["name"]), "is at", (monster["health"]),"health")
                user["health"] -= goblin["attack"]
                print("The goblin hit you for", goblin["attack"], "damage, you are at", user["health"])
            if user["health"] < 0:
                print("You were killed by the ")

        print("You killed the goblin!")

battle(player, goblin)
```

I know it's a weird question.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better solution: Make an Entity class, with Player and Goblin subclasses, and make `attack` a method.

Comment: Alternatively, if you _really_ want to use dictionaries, you can store a function in it instead of a string. `d = {"attack": lambda: random.randint(1,3)}; print(d["attack"]())`

Comment: Thanks for the input, I think I'll go with creating a class.  I haven't covered that yet in my python course so it will be a good opportunity to learn something new.

Comment: So I've created a class for Player.  I defined the variables gold, exp, and weapon.  How do I change those when something happens in the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won’t be able to use an `int()`, you’d have to [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval), which normally is recommended against—security issues may not be a huge issue for a game, but it’d also be, subjectively, a somewhat clunky and inelegant design.

Disregarding the bigger design picture, is there anything preventing you from simply defining attacks as anonymous functions in your dictionaries?

```
player = {"attack": lambda: random.randint(2, 4), "health": 50}
```

This way later you can do, for example,

```
goblin["health"] -= player["attack"]()
```

You can also have damage calculation defined as independent function:

```
player = {"attack_skill_factor": 2, "health": 50, "defense_skill_factor": 2}
goblin = {"attack_skill_factor": 1, "health": 30, "defense_skill_factor": 1}

def calculate_damage(aggressor, victim):
    return (
        random.randint(1, 3) *
        aggressor['attack_skill_factor'] /
        victim['defense_skill_factor'])

# Action
damage = calculate_damage(goblin, player)
player['health'] -= damage
print(
    "The goblin hit you for {damage} damage, "
    "you are at {health}".
    format(damage=damage, health=player['health'])
```

Next logical step would probably be using classes to define players and NPCs in an OOP manner.

Comment: This is what I'm getting now.  'The goblin hit you for <function <lambda> at 0x7f424f2e2c80> damage, you are at 49'.  How do I get it to print the number that was randomly selected instead of the function?

Comment: @JohnBobst, your output makes me think you forgot the parens ``()`` to actually invoke the lambda.

Comment: Ah, I see. To later report the damage number, you have to remember it in a variable, because each lambda invocation will return new random number.

Comment: Iterated on my example somewhat

Answer (score 1):

Why not use:

```
    player = {"attack":"2-4", "health": 50}

    goblin = {"name": "goblin", "attack": "1-3", "health": 30}
```

then use a split (using '-' as the delimiter string) to get the upper and lower bounds of the attack, then you can calculate a random value inside the loop:

```
    user["attack"] = random.randint(int(player["attack"].split('-')[0], int(player["attack"].split('-')[1])
```